# How to get the most related row from a pandas dataframe by iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-science

Let's assume I have a dataframe like this:

| name | color | shape | taste |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red | Heart | Sweet |
| Banana | Yellow | Long | Sweet |
| Cherry | Pink | Circular | Sour |
| Damson | Magenta | Circular | Sour |
| Eggplant | Violet | Long | Bitter |

And for the input I have a dictionary of one element which be like `new_fruit = {'name' : 'Tangerine' , 'color' : 'Orange' , 'shape' : 'Circular', 'taste' : 'Sour'}`

What I want is to iterate over this dictionary to get the most identical row(value) from the dataframe. In this case, **Circular** and **Sour** which are the **Damson** and **Cherry** rows.

I have tried with code

```
   for key, value in new_fruit.items():
    if key == 'name':
        continue
    if dataframe[key] == value: # Tried with isin too
        print(dataset[dataset[key] == value])
        break
```

I know something is wrong, but couldn't figure it out, can you please help me solve this!

Comment: What would be your expected output? A list, a dataframe...what?

Comment: Hello, @richardec , my expected output be like a list of ['cherry','damson'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
mask = df == pd.Series(new_fruit)
items = df.loc[mask.any(axis=1), 'name'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> items
['Cherry', 'Damson']
```

Comment: Thank you @richarded, this ```mask`` method worked like a charm. I thought I need to iterate over the new dictionary. Now this is solved. Sorry for that I couldn't cast vote as my reputation is too low.